# django - Load template and add a load spinner while Django data is loading

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

When I open my Django project, I want first to load body.html and then dashboard.html.
dashboard.html is a heavy file as its working with python dataframes in the script tag.
So first I want to display body.html and once body.html is render, add a load spinner while dashboard.html and its python Django data are loading

This actual code is not showing the Highcharts data as the body Class (DashboardGraphs) does not contain the Django data so there's no data for show in body.html

So, the question is how can I load first body.html AND then dashboard.html which Is inside body.html (dashboard-container). With the code I showed, that Is happening but the charts are not showing data.

This is body.html now
[image]

And this is dashboard.html
[image]

Thanks.

### urls.py

```py
path('dashboard_graphs', DashboardViewFinal.as_view() , name='dashboard_graphs'),
path('dashboard', DashboardGraphs.as_view() , name='dashboard'),
```

### views.py

```py
class DashboardViewFinal(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dashboard_view_23 = DashboardView(2023,'2023')
        self.year_int_2023 = 2023
        self.year_str_2023 = str(2023)

        self.dashboard_view_22 = DashboardView(2022, '2022')
        self.year_int_2022 = 2022
        self.year_str_2022 = str(2022)

    template_name = 'dashboard.html'

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # -----------------------------------------------
    # Conexion con HTML
    # -----------------------------------------------

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['panel'] = 'Panel de administrador'       

        
        context['month_total_2022'] = self.dashboard_view_22.get_graph_month_total()
        context['alumnos_mens_total_valor_2022'] = self.dashboard_view_22.get_graph_alumnos_mensual()
        context['month_total_2022'] = self.dashboard_view_22.get_graph_month_total()
        context['ingresos_total_2022'] = self.dashboard_view_22.get_ingresos_total()[0]
        context['egresos_total_2022'] = self.dashboard_view_22.get_ingresos_total()[1]
        context['saldo_total_2022'] = self.dashboard_view_22.get_ingresos_total()[2]

        context['month_total_2023'] = self.dashboard_view_23.get_graph_month_total()
        context['alumnos_mens_total_valor_2023'] = self.dashboard_view_23.get_graph_alumnos_mensual()
        context['month_total_2023'] = self.dashboard_view_23.get_graph_month_total()
        context['ingresos_total_2023'] = self.dashboard_view_23.get_ingresos_total()[0]
        context['egresos_total_2023'] = self.dashboard_view_23.get_ingresos_total()[1]
        context['saldo_total_2023'] = self.dashboard_view_23.get_ingresos_total()[2]      

        return context

class DashboardGraphs(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'hzt/body.html'
```

### body.html

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini" >
        
    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
        {% include 'hzt/header.html' %}
        <!-- Content -->
        {% include 'hzt/navbar.html' %}

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content">                    
                    {% block content %}
                    <div id="dashboard-container"></div>
                    <div id="spinner" class="loading-icon" style="display: none;">
                        <img style="height:50%; width: 100%;" src="https://media.tenor.com/6gHLhmwO87sAAAAi/gg.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
                    </div>
                    {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div> 
    <!-- Block javascript -->
    {% block javascript %}



    <script>

        function loadDashboard() {
            const container = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
            const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
            //const dashboard = initDashboardGraphs();
            spinner.style.display = 'block';

            
            fetch('{% url "erp:dashboard_graphs" %}')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => {
                    container.innerHTML = html;
                    const dashboard = window.initDashboardGraphs();
                    dashboard.showYear(2023);                    
                    spinner.style.display = 'none';
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error loading dashboard:', error);
                    spinner.style.display = 'none';
                });
                 
        }


        

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            loadDashboard();
            
            
        });

    </script>
{% endblock %}
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

### dashboard.html

```html
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Mes y año -->
        <div class="info-box mb-3 bg-warning">
            <span class="info-box-icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content padding-top">
                <h1><span class="info-box-text">2023</span>
                    <span class="info-box-number">HOLA</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.info-box-content -->
        </div> 
    </div>   


    

    <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Ingresos y egresos - mensual -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card bg-gradient-primary">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <div id="container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; min-height: 250px"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Alumnos Total - mensual -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card bg-gradient-primary">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="container-72" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "padre" >
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Ingresos y Egresos</a>

                    </div>
                </nav>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">             
                <div class="card card-success">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Ingresos y Gastos, proporción del total</h3>
                        <div class="card-tools">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div id="container-11" style="min-height: 250px; height: 450px; max-height: 550px; max-width: 100%;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div id="container-12" style="min-height: 250px; height: 450px; max-height: 550px; max-width: 100%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-success">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Gastos Variables</h3>
                        <div class="card-tools">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="chart" >
                            <div id="container-130" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<script type="application/javascript">
    function initDashboardGraphs() {

    const month_total_2022 =                      {{month_total_2022|safe}}
    const month_total_2023 =                      {{month_total_2023|safe}}
    const graph_ingresos_total_2022 =             {{graph_ingresos_total_2022|safe}}
    const graph_egresos_total_2022 =             {{graph_egresos_total_2022|safe}}
    const graph_saldo_total_2022 =                 {{graph_saldo_total_2022|safe}}
    const graph_ingresos_total_2023 =             {{graph_ingresos_total_2023|safe}}
    const graph_egresos_total_2023 =             {{graph_egresos_total_2023|safe}}
    const graph_saldo_total_2023 =                 {{graph_saldo_total_2023|safe}}
    const alumnos_mens_total_valor_2022 =         {{alumnos_mens_total_valor_2022|safe}}
    const alumnos_mens_total_valor_2023 =         {{alumnos_mens_total_valor_2023|safe}}



    function createHighchartsColumn(containerId, chartTitle, chartSubtitle, xAxisCategories, yAxisTitle, yAxisMin, plotOptions, tooltipFormatter, seriesData) {
             return Highcharts.chart(containerId, {
                 chart: {
                     type: 'column',
                     borderColor: '#000000',
                     borderWidth: 1,
                 },
                 title: {
                     text: chartTitle
                 },
                 subtitle: {
                     text: chartSubtitle
                 },
                 xAxis: {
                     categories: xAxisCategories,
                     crosshair: true
                 },
                 yAxis: {
                     min: yAxisMin,
                     title: {
                         text: yAxisTitle
                     }
                 },
                 tooltip: {
                     headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                     pointFormat: tooltipFormatter,
                     footerFormat: '</table>',
                     shared: true,
                     useHTML: true
                 },
                 plotOptions: plotOptions,
                 series: seriesData
             });
         }

    var IngyEgrTotal = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                                 chart: {
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Ingresos y Egresos'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'mensual'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: {{month_total_2023|safe}},
                            crosshair: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: -10000,
                            title: {
                                text: '$'
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} $</b></td></tr>',
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                            shared: true,
                            useHTML: true
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            },
                            series: { borderColor: '#303030'},
                        },
                        series: [{
                                                name: 'Ingresos',
                                                color: 'green',
                                                
                                                data: {{graph_ingresos_total_2023 | safe}}

                                            }, {
                                                name: 'Egresos',
                                                color: 'orange',
                                                
                                                data: {{graph_egresos_total_2023 | safe}}

                                            }, {
                                                name: 'Saldo',
                                                'negativeColor': 'red',
                                                
                                                data: {{graph_saldo_total_2023 | safe}}

                                            } 
                                                 ]

                                             });

    var AlumnosTotMes = createHighchartsColumn(
             'container-72',
             'Alumnos totales, por mes',
             '',
             {{ month_total_2023 | safe }},
             'Cantidad',
             0,
             { series: { borderColor: '#303030' } },
             '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                 '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
             [{ name: 'Cantidad', showInLegend: false, data: {{ alumnos_mens_total_valor_2023 | safe }} }]
         );                                         

    var chartObjects = [
                {
                    chart: IngyEgrTotal,
                    data: () => {
                        var ingresos = (year === 2022) ? graph_ingresos_total_2022 : graph_ingresos_total_2023;
                        var egresos = (year === 2022) ? graph_egresos_total_2022 : graph_egresos_total_2023;
                        var saldo = (year === 2022) ? graph_saldo_total_2022 : graph_saldo_total_2023;
                        return [
                            { data: ingresos },
                            { data: egresos },
                            { data: saldo }
                        ];
                    }
                },
                
                { chart: AlumnosTotMes, data: () => (year === 2022) ? {{ alumnos_mens_total_valor_2022 | safe }}  : {{ alumnos_mens_total_valor_2023 | safe }}  }, 
            ];     

    var year = 2023; // Default year

    function showYear(selectedYear) {
      year = selectedYear;
      var month_total = (year === 2022) ? month_total_2022 : month_total_2023;

      chartObjects.forEach(chartObject => {
          chartObject.chart.update({
              xAxis: {
                  categories: month_total
              },
              series: chartObject.data()
          });
      });

      const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
        spinner.style.display = 'none';

      


    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: please make clear what is your question.

Comment: The question is how can I load first body.html AND then dashboard.html which Is inside body.html (<div id="dashboard-container"></div>). With the code I showed that Is happening but the charts are not showing data.

Answer (score 0):

### Charts not being shown:

`<div class="container-fluid" style="display:none;">` inside of `dashboard.html` is never turned off, so you're never showing the Div!

Changing this won't give you the desired results tho. This is because you're fetching the spinner;
This means when the spinner has been shown, the fetch is done and you **aren't** waiting anymore- sorta defeats the purpose!

### Desired behavior:

Moving the Spinner inside of `body.html`, and some minor changes, *should*  give you the results you're looking for.

#### #1 Move the spinner

Remove the spinner element inside `dashboard.html` and instead place it inside of `body.html` like:

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">                    
  {% block content %}
    <div id="dashboard-container">

      <!-- Show spinner on load -->
      <div id="spinner" class="loading-icon">
          <img style = "height:50%; width: 100%;" src="https://media.tenor.com/6gHLhmwO87sAAAAi/gg.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
      </div>

    </div>
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

#### #2 Change `dashboard.html`

Remove `display:none` from container-fluid inside `dashboard.html`

```html
<!-- show container when loaded -->
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div id="ajax-content"></div>
  <!-- other contents -->

</div>
```

#### #3 Update loadDashboard in `body.html`

```js
function loadDashboard() {
    // Remove all the spinner JavaScript
    const container = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');

    fetch('{% url "erp:dashboard_graphs" %}')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
                // spinner will be remove by innerHTML
                container.innerHTML = html;                    
                })
    .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading dashboard:', error);
            // possibly empty the container to remove the spinner?
            });
}
```

---

#### Conclusion:

1. `body.html` will **load** with the spinner rendered, and start the fetch
2. when fetch finshes, `dashboard.html` will overwrite spinner - removing it
3. `dashboard.html` is visible by default, so will show by default

Comment: I made changes you said (I updated the post with these updates) but still not getting results. Now the graphs containers are being shown but with no data. I think the issue is that the class for body.html in views.py is not calling any python data, so although with fetch I'm calling "dashboard.html", the graphs will be displayed in "body.html" which has no idea what to show bc in its class there's nothing but a template_name.

Comment: Okay, so if you go to `{my_project}/dashboard_graphs` it all works, just not when fetching it.
Seems like a **JavaScript problem**, I recommend doing some `console.log()`s and make sure:
**1** stuff like `month_total_2022` has data and, **2** make sure `showYear` is being called, and **3** just start stepping through.
I don't see anything obviously wrong at this point.. But no, you're in the right direction here with the views. Putting any of the data inside of `body.html`'s class would defeat the purpose of what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** As @Nealium said it was a JS problem and the order I was calling the functions. Here my solution: In body.html I added the function I was calling from dashboard.html, so, I removed all JS scripts and added this to body.html

```
function loadDashboard() {
        const container = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
        const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');        
        spinner.style.display = 'block';

        fetch('/erp/dashboard_graphs')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(html => {
                container.innerHTML = html; 

                window.initDashboardGraphs = function () {  

                var data_ropa_2022 =                                JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data_ropa_2022').textContent)                    
                var month_total_2022 =                              JSON.parse(document.getElementById('month_total_2022').textContent)

                var IngyEgrRopa = createHighchartsColumn(
                                 'container-43',
                                 ' ',//Cantidad de Alumnos por Clase, por Mes 
                                 '',
                                  month_total_2022 ,
                                 '$',
                                 -10000,
                                 { series: { borderColor: '#303030' } },
                                 '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                     '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} $</b></td></tr>',
                                  data_ropa_2023 
                             );            

                var chartObjects = [
                        { chart: IngyEgrRopa, data: () => (year === 2022) ? data_ropa_2022 : data_ropa_2023}   
                    ];
                
                var year = 2023; // Default year
                function showYear(selectedYear) { ... }                                

                
                } 

    try {
        initDashboardGraphs().showYear(2023); 
        console.log('Good');         
        
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.log(error);     
    }    
    
    spinner.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('Good');

    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading dashboard:', error);
        spinner.style.display = 'none';
    });     


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
loadDashboard();
});
```